# Scrapy - Why Css Selector / Xpath return diferent outputs?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am a newbie on scrapy.

I have made two different codes.  In my opinion, they should return the same output.  But they are not!

### Code 01 - With CSS Selector

```
import scrapy
from ..items import QuotetutorialItem

class QuoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        all_div_quotes = response.css('div.quote')[0]
        title = all_div_quotes.css('span.text::text').extract()
        author = all_div_quotes.css('.author::text').extract()
        tag = all_div_quotes.css('.tag::text').extract()
        yield {
            'title': title,
            'author': author,
            'tag': tag
        }
```

#### Output

```
{'title': ['“The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.”'], 'author': ['Albert Einstein'], 'tag': ['change', 'deep-thoughts', 'thinking', 'world']}
```

### Code with Xpath just on title

```
import scrapy
from ..items import QuotetutorialItem

class QuoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        all_div_quotes = response.css('div.quote')[0]
        title = all_div_quotes.xpath('//span[@class="text"]/text()').extract()
        author = all_div_quotes.css('.author::text').extract()
        tag = all_div_quotes.css('.tag::text').extract()
        yield {
            'title': title,
            'author': author,
            'tag': tag
        }
```

#### Output

```
{'title': ['“The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.”', '“It is our choices, Harry, that show what we truly are, far more than our abilities.”', '“There are only two ways to live your life. One is as though nothing is a miracle. The other is as though everything is a miracle.”', '“The person, be it gentleman or lady, who has not pleasure in a good novel, must be intolerably stupid.”', "“Imperfection is beauty, madness is genius and it's better to be absolutely ridiculous than absolutely boring.”", '“Try not to become a man of success. Rather become a man of value.”', '“It is better to be hated for what you are than to be loved for what you are not.”', "“I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.”", "“A woman is like a tea bag; you never know how strong it is until it's in hot water.”", '“A day without sunshine is like, you know, night.”'], 'author': ['Albert Einstein'], 'tag': ['change', 'deep-thoughts', 'thinking', 'world']}
```

### The problem

With **CSS Selector** using `title = all_div_quotes.css('span.text::text').extract()` it returned just the first element since I was setting `all_div_quotes = response.css('div.quote')[0]`.

Instead, using **XPATH Selector** on `title = all_div_quotes.xpath('//span[@class="text"]/text()').extract()` the code had returned all the quotes from the page.

Can anyone give me any clue why is it happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have a dot missing in the xpath to specify you want to look only under the current node. Changing your xpath to `all_div_quotes.xpath('.//span[@class="text"]/text()').extract()` should give the same result as the css-selector.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  As i said, i am a newbie.  Sorry by this dumb mistake.